# ReactJS - pass values to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a component where user inputs a number:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Place_holder from './place_holder';

class Body extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: ""};
    }

    handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={event => this.handleChange(event.target.value)}
                />

                <Place_holder num={this.state.value}  />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Body;
```

The value gets passed to Place_holder where three different elements are supposed to do 3 different things (for the argument's sake: Column 1: num x 2, Column 2: num / 2, Column 3: num X num). Now as I type the number in the input box, it gets automatically updated in the three columns but whenever I try to write any method to apply to the number and change it in real time, I get all sorts of errors

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Place_holder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">{this.props.num}</div>
                    <div className="col-md-4">{this.props.num}</div>
                    <div className="col-md-4">{this.props.num}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Place_holder;
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never modify props** directly, instead compute what you need from them.

For example:

```
render() {
    const column1 = this.props.num*2;
    const column2 = this.props.num/2;
    const column3 = this.props.num*this.props.num;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4">{column1}</div>
                <div className="col-md-4">{column2}</div>
                <div className="col-md-4">{column3}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks. One question: what's the difference between defining methods / constants within the render() function and just above it after the constructor?

Comment: You don't need to define functions within render(), because on every component rerender they will be redefined - so move all functions after the constructor. On the other hand, computed properties I always define in render(), because they need to be recomputed whenever component needs to rerender itself.